# error: constructor LineData in class LineData cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I've been following this tutorial https://www.studytutorial.in/android-line-chart-or-line-graph-using-mpandroid-library-tutorial to create a simple line chart. I keep getting the error `error: constructor LineData in class LineData cannot be applied to given types;
required: ILineDataSet[]
found: ArrayList<Entry>,ArrayList<ILineDataSet>
reason: varargs mismatch; ArrayList<Entry> cannot be converted to ILineDataSet`
and the error is on this line `LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);`

This is my first time creating a chart on android. I've looked at some different tutorials but they all seem to come up with the same errors

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.LimitLine;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Graph extends Fragment {

    public Graph() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    private LineChart mChart;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);
        mChart = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.linechart);
        //add data
        setData();
        //set description for no data
        mChart.setNoDataText("Enter a blood glucose level input to create a chart");
        //enable touch
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        //enable scaling and dragging
        mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        //get the legend
        /*
        Legend 1 = mChart.getLegend();
        1.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE); */

        LimitLine upper_limit = new LimitLine(8f, "Upper Limit");
        upper_limit.setLineWidth(4f);
        upper_limit.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        upper_limit.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_TOP);
        upper_limit.setTextSize(10f);

        LimitLine lower_limit = new LimitLine(4f, "Lower Limit");
        lower_limit.setLineWidth(4f);
        lower_limit.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        lower_limit.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);
        lower_limit.setTextSize(10f);

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        // reset all limit lines to avoid overlapping lines
        leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines();
        leftAxis.addLimitLine(upper_limit);
        leftAxis.addLimitLine(lower_limit);
        leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(220f);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(-50f);
        //leftAxis.setYOffset(20f);
        leftAxis.enableGridDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        leftAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);

        // limit lines are drawn behind data (and not on top)
        leftAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        return view;
    }

    //store x-axis values
    private ArrayList<Entry> setXAxisValues(){
        ArrayList<Entry> xVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        xVals.add(new Entry(0,16));
        xVals.add(new Entry(1,2));
        xVals.add(new Entry(10,5));
        xVals.add(new Entry(12,5));
        xVals.add(new Entry(3,4));

        return xVals;
    }
    //store y-axis values
    private ArrayList<Entry> setYAxisValues(){
        ArrayList<Entry> yVals = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        yVals.add(new Entry(0,16));
        yVals.add(new Entry(1,2));
        yVals.add(new Entry(10,5));
        yVals.add(new Entry(12,5));
        yVals.add(new Entry(3,4));

        return yVals;
    }

    //populate graph
    private void setData() {
        ArrayList<Entry> xVals = setXAxisValues();
        ArrayList<Entry> yVals = setYAxisValues();
        LineDataSet set1;
            //create a dataset and give it a type
            set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "DataSet 1");
            set1.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
            set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
            set1.setLineWidth(1f);
            set1.setCircleRadius(3f);
            set1.setValueTextSize(9f);

            ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
            //add the data sets
            dataSets.add(set1);
            //create data object with the datasets
            **LineData data = new LineData(xVals, dataSets);**
            //set data
            mChart.setData(data);
    }

}
```

I've marked the problem line with **

I think the tutorials I'm looking at maybe outdated, so the issue might be that the library has changed since it was updated.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: In that tutorial, `xVals` – and the return type of `setXAxisValues()` – is an `ArrayList<String>`, not `ArrayList<Entry>`. It looks like you accidentally copied `setYAxisValues()` there for your `setXAxisValues()` method.

Comment: Btw, for general Android programming questions, the correct tag is `[android]`. The `[android-studio]` tag is for questions specifically about the IDE.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the help. I changed it to the <String> array, but the same error still occurs

Comment: Seems `LineData` doesn't take x-values anymore: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineData.java. It's apparently been like that for more than three years, judging from the commit message, so, yeah, your tutorial is a little outdated.